# R API Error: No method for S4 class:SingleGroupClass and Index Out of Bounds

Tags: r, rest

I am trying to creating an R API to run a the `mirt` function from the `mirt` library for my Next.js Application. When I run a fetch, I get the following error(s):

```
<simpleError: No method for S4 class:SingleGroupClass>
Error in run_now(check_time, all = FALSE) : 
  Index out of bounds: [index='status'].
```

The following is the code for my R API:

```
library(mirt)
library(plumber)
library(jsonlite)
library(later)

#* @apiTitle MIRT IRT API
#* @apiDescription API for performance IRT with 'mirt' packgage

#* @post /estimate_difficulty
function(req) {
  # LOAD DATA FROM REQUEST BODY
  data <- req$body
  print(data)
  dataFrame <- data.frame(A = data$A,
                          B = data$B,
                          C = data$C,
                          D = data$D,
                          E = data$E,
                          F = data$F)
  print(dataFrame)
  print(dim(dataFrame))
  
  # PERFORMAN IRT ANALYSIS
  
  model <- mirt(data = dataFrame,
                  model = "F1 = 1-6",
                  itemtype = '2PL',
                  verbose = FALSE)
}

# Programmatically alter your API
#* @plumber
function(pr) {
  pr %>%
    # Overwrite the default serializer to return unboxed JSON
    pr_set_serializer(serializer_unboxed_json())
}
```

Originally, I tested the exact same code logic locally in another R script (Not an API) and it works fine and produces an output. I have also tested and eliminated any issues with the data input from Next.js ensuring that no errors occur up until the `mirt` function is executed.

Having throughly tested the `mirt` function, I have come to the conclusion that issue must lay with the API (and/or Plumber).

While the final step of the following has not been implemented in my API, this is my eventual expected output:
[image]